# Update by key (integer) security issue

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, security

Our database has integers for primary keys. Let's assume a use case where there are representatives who manage different customers assigned to them. One scenario is that the representative can update customer contact information. Our page displays the contact information by the id. When the representative presses update, it updates using the id. This brings up a security issue if the representative changes the id, they can view and also update the contact information of other customer (who may not be assigned to them). I believe this is a common problem.

One way might be to keep a key in the session, encrypt the id and decrypt it on update using that key. Is there a better way?

Also, since the same has to be done for various pages, is there a generic approach that we can follow in asp.net mvc?

Comment: You can simply use some kind of salting. Generate GUID everytime, insert your id in between (but at specific place). And while sending it out, use this salting. When you receive it in query string, took out your id and through away other stuff. For this you can write static class, which will be used by all.

Comment: Could you tell which classes to use to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have representatives with customers assigned to them, I assume you have this information stored on your database in some form of Access Control List, right?

If this is the case, then you should enforce on the server that user X has permissions to see/change/delete customer Y. Check that permission on both GET /Edit/Customer/1 and POST /Edit/Customer/1 and you should be good to go.

Since you didn't show any code or DB schema I can't give you a more specific example, but I hope I explained myself.

Comment: This may not be an option because there are many things in Customer that the representatives can edit. Let's say Contact, Order, etc. To edit contact, the url may look like /edit/customercontact?customerId=1&contactId=1. Now we need to check if the contact id belongs to customer and customer belongs to correct representative. Similarly if there is one more level, it becomes difficult to validate all. I cannot give db schema as this example is made up but very similar to our use case.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are showing the ID in query string and user can change that. First of all don't do that. User sensitive information should never be passed in query string as plain text. You can use Encryption to encrypt the id's and then retrieve it later.

Comment: Once the value is hashed, you can not retrieve it. Either some salting or encryption need to be used.